# Returning structs inside a class

Tags: class, structure

I am converting my application to an OOP type but I am having problem with helper functions. What I did was place helper functions inside the class as private. How should I declare a function "addSection" to return a struct

This is for my .cpp file

```
section_t XIniFile::*addSection(ini_file_t *n, char *d)
{
    section_t *s = (section_t *)malloc(sizeof(section_t *); 
    //add sections
    return s;
}
```

This is for my .h file

```
class XIniFile
{
public: 
    int open(const char *);
    int readString(const char *, const char *, char *);
    int readInt(const char *, const char *, int *);
    int writeString(const char *, const char *, char *);
    int writeInt(const char *, const char *, int *);
    int close();

private:

    typedef struct key_tag {
        char *name;
        char *value;
        key_tag *next;
    } key_tag_t;

    typedef struct sections_tag {
        char *name;
        sections_tag *next;
        key_tag_t *keys;
    } section_t;

    typedef struct {
        char *name;
        section_t *sections;
        int modified;
    } ini_file_t;

    section_t *add_section(ini_file_t *, char *);
    key_tag_t *add_key(section_t *, char *, char *);
};
```

There are a lot of errors but I would like to start first from the first error which is `error: ‘section_t’ does not name a type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turn add_section into:

```
XIniFile::section_t * XIniFile::add_section(ini_file_t *n, char *d)
```

since section_t is a member of XIniFile

Comment: @Gibs - I upvoted Serve's answer. It is customary on Stack Overflow to upvote an answer that you found helpful.

Comment: Yeah I actually want to upvote it but unfortunately I only got 12 reps lol

Answer (score 0):

Your struct section_t and other structs need to be declared above the functions that use them, like add_section. C++ type declarations are forward visible, meaning their visibility extend from the point they are first declared onward, but not behind. Order matters, it is an inherited trait of the C language, based on "textual" treatment of include files as opposed to true modules or multi file type metadata, where the compiler traditionally notes each type as it is declared syntactically, stores it in a symbol table, where it is immediately available.

This differs from Java or C# compilers which parse the whole source file first, then resolve types and symbols later, removing order from the equation.

Another error, your * is in the wrong place, move it to directly after section_t:

```
section_t XIniFile::*addSection(ini_file_t *n, char *d)
```

Change to:

```
XIniFile::section_t* XIniFile::addSection(ini_file_t *n, char *d)
```

Also, in C++ you don't have to use typedef for structs as in C. You can simply say:

```
struct key_tag_t {
   char *name;
   char *value;
   key_tag_t *next;
};

struct section_t {
   char *name;
   sections_tag *next;
   key_tag_t *keys;
};

section_t *add_section(ini_file_t *, char *);
key_tag_t *add_key(section_t *, char *, char *);
```

structs and classes are implicitly "typedefed" in C++, though there is a minor difference, it isn't relevant.

Comment: Thanks codenheim for a prompt response, i already tried that but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: I'm not sure which problem you mean. You can't use a type before it is declared. I would assume the error message is different.

Comment: add_section returns a section_t structure that's why I should implement it with `section_t XIniFile::*addSection(ini_file_t *n, char *d)`

Comment: See my edit. Your * is in the wrong place. It needs to be beside the type.  T* means pointer to T. You need to keep the * beside T. There is no legal syntax Foo::*bar that I know of.

Comment: You edited the question after my answer, fixing per my first suggestion, without noting it in the question. This will be confusing to future readers. It is best to note when you edit, because it may invalidate answers.